# 'Lvalue required as increment operand' error in C

Tags: c

Here is my code snippet:

```
void readandprint(){
    int* num = (int*) malloc (10* sizeof(int));
    for (int i =0;i<10;i++){
        *(num+i) = 0;
    }
    char c;
    while (scanf("%c",&c)==1){
        if (c>='0'&&c<='9'){
            *(num+c-'0')++ ; //error here
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0;j < 10;j++){
        printf("%d ",*(num+j));
    }
}
```

And then i got the 'Lvalue required as increment operand' error. When i replace "++" with "+=1" the code works just fine. Can anybody tell me why? Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Try `(*(num+c-'0'))++;` or `num[c-'0']++;`. (Your problem is to do with operator precedence.)

Comment: @IanAbbott: In particular, I think your second suggestion is a lot more readable.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int* num = (int*) malloc (10* sizeof(int));`  1)  in c, the returned type is `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer.   Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing the cast.    2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  if not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "your error message");` to have both your error message and the text reason the error occurred output to `stderr`.

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (c>='0'&&c<='9'){`   Much better, clearer, and works with non contiguous digits to do: `#include <ctype.h>` and `if( isdigit( c ) )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)
Increment operator has higher priority than indirection operator.
So, you expression is evaluated like *((num+c-'0')++), where subexpression
(num+c-'0') is not a [lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) and can not appear on the left-hand side of an increment operator.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to increase the referenced int then you need to:

```
 (*(num+c-'0'))++
```